# Are there infinitely many $n$ s.t. $\prod_i^n a_i = \sum^n_i a_i$ only if the number of $1$ in vector $(a_i)_i \in \mathbb{N}^n$ is $n-2$?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

For $n \geq 4$, let
$$A_{n} = \left\{ \mathbf{a} = (a_{1}, a_{2}, \ldots, a_{n}) \in \mathbb{N}^{n} : \prod_{i}^{n} a_{i} = \sum_{i}^{n} a_{i} \right\}$$
and for a vector $\mathbf{a} \in \mathbb{N}^{n}$, let $m(\mathbf{a})$ be the number of $1$ in $\mathbf{a}$.
It is clear that $(n, 2, 1_{1}, 1_{2}, \ldots, 1_{n-2}) \in A_{n}$ which implies that $A_{n} \neq \varnothing$ and there exists a vector $\mathbf{a} \in A_{n}$ such that $m(\mathbf{a}) = n - 2$.
Besides, for each vector $\mathbf{a} \in A_{n}$, $m(\mathbf{a}) \leq n-2$ holds.

There exists some $n \geq 4$ such that for every vector $\mathbf{a} \in A_{n}$, $m(\mathbf{a})$ is exactly $n - 2$.
After my computing, the solution for $n \leq 1000$ with at most $m$ integers greater than $1$ is presented as follow:

[image]

Specifically, such $n \leq 1000$ satisfying that the number of $1$ in the vector $\mathbf{a} \in A_{n}$ is exactly $n - 2$ is listed as follow:
4, 6, 7, 9, 10, 15, 16, 22, 24, 31, 34, 36, 49, 66, 76, 91, 97, 112, 114, 126, 142, 174, 210, 231, 330, 442, 444, 664, 714, 780, 784, 966.

My question is whether there are infinitely many $n \geq 4$ such that for every vector $\mathbf{a} \in A_{n}$, the number of $1$ in $\mathbf{a}$ is exactly $n - 2$.

**PS:** Let $B_{l} = \{ n : \forall \mathbf{a} \in A_{n}, m(\mathbf{a}) \geq n - l \}$. Actually, I what to know whether the size of $B_{2}$ is infinite.
It is welcome if you have an idea about the weak version of this problem: Determine whether the size of $B_{l}$ is infinite for some constant $l$.

Comment: Not sure I understand the rules.  For $n=4$, $\{1,2,3,1.2\}$ has the both product and sum $7.2$  and it has only one $1$.  More broadly, $\{a,b,c,\frac {a+b+c}{abc-1}\}$ works so long as $abc\neq 1$.  Why aren't these counterexamples to your claim?

Comment: @lulu OP is asking for integer sequences

Comment: @Astyx Yes, thank you

Comment: @Astyx  Ah, natural numbers even.  Kind of buried in there.  Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: For $n=3$ the only solution I can find in natural numbers is $\{1,2,3\}$ which has exactly one $1$.  Have I missed a solution?

Comment: @lulu $n$ is no less than $4$.

Comment: But why?  The claim seems to hold for $n=2$ and $n=3$ as well, right?

Comment: What's a counterexample for $n=5$?

Comment: For $n=5$, $(2,2,2,1,1)$

Comment: @Astyx  Thanks again.

Comment: What about the following question: The integer $n$ such that the equation holds only if there are at most 2 integers in $\mathbf{a}$ lager than $1$.

Comment: @Blanco how can you prove that all the $a_i$'s should be bounded above by $n$? this seems to be true. if you want to make sure that your computations are right you need to know that the set is finite.

Comment: @mathma That's easy, assume that $a_{1} \geq a_{2} \geq \cdots a_{m} > a_{m+1} = \cdots = a_{n} = 1$. Then we have $P - S := \prod_{i =1}^{m} a_{i} - \sum_{i=1}^{m} a_{i} = n - m$. Note that when we increase $a_{k}$ by $1$ ($1 \leq k \leq m$), then $P - S$ becomes larger. Thus the number of the vectors satisfying that $P - S = n - m \leq n$ is bounded.

Comment: A necessary condition: it must be $(p+1)/2$ for prime $p$. This may help to search further numbers.

Answer (score 1):

This might be of interest if you have not already analysed numbers of the following form.

**Solutions for $n$  with $3$ numbers greater than $1$.**

If $abc=a+b+c+n-3$ then $$an+a^2-3a+1=(ab-1)(ac-1).$$ Let $a=2$. Then $2n-1=(2b-1)(2c-1)$ i.e. there is a solution if $2n-1$ is composite.

Let $a=3$. Then $3n+1=(3b-1)(3c-1)$ i.e. there is a solution if $3n+1$ is the product of factors which are   congruent to $2$ modulo $3$ and greater than $2$.

Similarly, if  $4n+5$ is the product of factors which are  congruent to $3$ modulo $4$ and greater than $3$.

And if $5n+11$ is the product of factors which are  congruent to $4$ modulo $5$ and greater than $4$.

The pattern continues for $6n+19,7n+29,8n+41,9n+55, ...$

**A different result using a similar method**

If $4n+1$, with $n>2$,  has a factor congruent to $3$ modulo $4$ then there is a solution with $3$ or more numbers greater than $1$ which uses $2,2,...$.

Comment: Thanks, I found this results for $m = 3$, ($m$ is the number of the nature numbers greater than $1$ in a solution). I believe there are infinitely many $n$ satisfying that each the solution with $m \neq 3$. But I am not sure for $m < 3$.

Comment: Thanks - its a very interesting problem. One method I tried makes it look as if there will only be a finite number for $m=2$ but it's a long way from being a proof.